# Keycloak SSO - too many redirects

Tags: angular, authentication, jenkins, single-sign-on, keycloak

When session is created in Angular4 using Keycloak-js (Version : 4.0.0), SSO is not working

**Following are the steps to Recreate this**

1. Integrate Keycloak with an Angular 4 Application (For instance: https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular or https://github.com/cternes/slackspace-angular2-spring-keycloak/tree/master/frontend)
2. When user tries to login, he would be automatically redirected to Keycloak Login Page
3. After session is created, try to login through another app like Grafana with Keycloak or Jenkins
4. Too many Redirects ( Keycloak is running in port 8081 & Grafana in 3000)

> Request url :

http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/angular_keycloak/protocol/openid-connect/auth?access_type=online&client_id=client-ui&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fgeneric_oauth&response_type=code&scope=read+write&state=wWXu1iyWXtSevSxwCFzWHPZ7oPM63Dbu5AoMBTMdjHE%3D

> Response URL:

http://localhost:3000/login/generic_oauth#state=wWXu1iyWXtSevSxwCFzWHPZ7oPM63Dbu5AoMBTMdjHE%3D&session_state=6ec8255b-ed4c-4399-951c-0241ce7bebad&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..lvjHquloACY0fTMxmOLeYQ.82mSmzkn4HJBSnokMEpqnZw-xkhUrKy9icZAUwVOrh8b4MP9F-8qmH42rrg0O_axTZVJYlozwWA4x9V2dQAIbi2cUgKJlsiNfJllcN8luK4PSwqOe2bp6WtMszvIeU30UW8RXVqf46hstf1dTxWZp-wocChwLaqATNqZD61u-AURLz6ItY8DQxd3hwScR1kJhfu8bJBR_Pcnbt8LIGl_nKOdaGfceoDFpBfOqGuy1AtQ-3QUwvNkBMZCSGVBYQLB.fSMESQYQKVWZfpbR1Rw47A

Options tried:

1. Angular4 & Jenkins
2. Angular4 & Grafana

Whereas the following steps works

1. Login to Grafana or Jenkins or to KeyCloak directly
2. Then login to Angular 4 , it works

Since I am able to login to each of these Apps separately and SSO works between Grafana & Jenkins, I am inclined to believe that issue could be with the Keycloak-Js adapter.

Following are the arguments that I use to create session

```
  const keycloakAuth: any = Keycloak({
            url: environment.KEYCLOAK_URL,
            realm: environment.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
            clientId: environment.KEYCLOAK_CLIENTID,
            'ssl-required': 'external',
            'public-client': true,
        });
```

Comment: Your used lib doesn't use implicit flow - https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/43, that's really insecure for Angular app. I'm really curious how it can works without client secret in your code. Use better lib, my recommendation https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/index.html.

Comment: thanks @JanGaraj . Will do a poc using angular oidc . To clarify, Keycloak-angular also uses implicit  flow only . The issue talks about the management of refresh token using implicit flow. Also, in my implementation client secret is not needed as i have set the access type as public in keycloak

Comment: I have faced the same issue. What caused the problem is parameters passed to init function. There cannot be "checkLoginIframe: false" passed because it disables keycloak adapter iframe holding authorization cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I implemented the SSO functionality using Angular-OIDC Library (Implicit Flow) https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

```
 private configureWithNewConfigApi() {
 // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
    this.oauthService.redirectUri = window.location.origin + "/index.html";

    // set the scope for the permissions the client should request
    this.oauthService.scope = "openid profile email";

    // set to true, to receive also an id_token via OpenId Connect (OIDC) in addition to the
    // OAuth2-based access_token
    this.oauthService.oidc = true;

    // Use setStorage to use sessionStorage or another implementation of the TS-type Storage
    // instead of localStorage
    this.oauthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);

    this.oauthService.clientId = "<<clientId>>";
    let url = 'https://<<keycloakhost>>:<<port>>/auth/realms/<<realmsname>>/.well-known/openid-configuration';
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument(url).then((doc) => {
        // This method just tries to parse the token within the url when
        // the auth-server redirects the user back to the web-app
        // It dosn't initiate the login
        this.oauthService.tryLogin({});      
        console.debug('discovery succeeded', doc);

    });
```

Thanks Jan Garag for your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225426/keycloak-sso-too-many-redirects/54473933#comment87523557_50225426)